# label and input not on the same margin in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How do I make my url and https:// to start on the same margin?

[image]

```
    <div className="card">  
        <div className="card-body">
            <div className="form-group col-12">
                <label className="">URL</label>
                <div className="row">
                    <p className=""> {baseURL} </p>
                    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value={url} onChange={this.onURLChange}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I imagine if you wrap `<label className="">URL</label>` in a `row` it should align as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `flexbox` as -

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your `label` with a `div` having same className (`row`) as you’ve done with your `input`, you might see the same result.

```
<div className = "row">
   <label className="">URL</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Just felt it should be consistent with the other input.

Comment: The class `.row` have styles on it in bootstrap, so the "consistend" approach would cause more harm. Also it's done with just two three lines of css.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would add the following to the class `form-group`, I also make the assumption you want some space between the label and input so I add a bit of padding which you can adjust.

```
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: .5rem;
}
```

Also add `for` on the label, have it match the input name it is for. Doing so clicking it will focus the input.

`<label for="url">URL</label>`